# React NodeJS Multer file upload failure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, multer

Im trying to single file upload to folder `public/files`, using `reactJS` as frontend, `multer` `nodeJS` as serverside :

**react**  :

here i have `file` input that accepts only `pdf` and `msword`, and `on change` it sets the `file` state, on submit it triggers function `handleCareer` which makes `formData` object and appends data from state, the `file.name` will be something like `1663010450031report.pdf`, and then make request to `/upload`.

```
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const handleCareer = async () => {


    const data = new FormData();
    const pdf = `${Date.now()}${file.name}`;
    data.append("file", pdf);

    try {
      await fetch("http://localhost:8000/upload", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

      <div className="uploadCV">
        <label htmlFor="resumeFile" className="downloadImg">
          <AddAPhotoIcon className="postIcon" />
          <span>Upload resume</span>
        </label>

        <input
          type="file"
          accept="application/pdf,application/msword"
          id="resumeFile"
          name="file"
          onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
        ></input>
      </div>

      <div className="submitUpload">
        <button type="button" onClick={handleCareer}>
          Request
        </button>
      </div>
```

**server** :

here im using path `public/files` as the target folder for upload and specifying in `destination` as well as specifying `req.body.file` for `filename`

```
app.use("/files", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/files")));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "public/files");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.file);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file");

app.post("/upload", function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      console.log(err);
    } else if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    return res.status(200).send(req.file);
  });
});
```

but the file is not uploading, and it doesn't console log any errors, on `postman` it gives empty result with status code `200` ..  what's is the problem here ?

Comment: You are send pdf which is a string (file name only), instead of pdf you should send file(state) which is a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't send the file field to backend. You have to send a file (like pdf). Now you are sending only a pdf name. There aren't any file.

```
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file");
```

Here you have defined the name of incoming data is file. So you should add the field which named file